# How to create range indicator in Xamarin Form?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, slider

I want to create this type of range indicator in Xamarin form.

[image]

Comment: Read this and rework your question please https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below open source Range Slider control for achieving your requirement.

https://github.com/halkar/xamarin-range-slider

It is also available in NuGet.org and it is free.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.RangeSlider/

Comment: @umair Noor: If my reply helps you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks :)